# Android: How to take a camera-shot and view it in Webview/ Imageview afterword?

Tags: android, webview, imageview

In my app, I am taking a shot and saving it using the built-in `Camera` app. Then, after taking the picture, my app return back to a blank `Activity`. All that works.

Now instead of saving and going back to an empty `Activity`, I want to view the taken shot on a `Webview` or an `Imageview` how to do that ?

I start `CameraAdapter` class from the `MainActivity` class as follow:

```
public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(this, CameraAdapter.class);
        startActivity(cameraIntent);
    }
```

.. and here is the `CameraAdapter` class:

```
public class CameraAdapter extends Activity {
    static Uri imageUri;
    static File imageFolderPath;
    int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    String imageFileName;
    ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imgs);                
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getUri());
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

    ImageView imageV = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
    String filename = getImageFileName();
    Bitmap image = getImage(filename);
    imageV.setImageBitmap(image);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Capture is saved to:\n" + imageFolderPath.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You cancelled the capture",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Capture failed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public Uri getUri(){
    imageFolderPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mst_imgs");
    if(!imageFolderPath.exists())
        imageFolderPath.mkdir();

    String imageFullName = imageFolderPath + "/" + getImageFileName();
    File newPic = new File(imageFullName);

    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(newPic);

    return imageUri;
}

private Bitmap getImage(String  imageFileName) {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root + "/mst_imgs/" + imageFileName);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root + "/mst_imgs/CS_TEST.jpg");
}

private String getImageFileName(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss");
    String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    //imageFileName = "CS_" +timeStamp + ".jpg";
    imageFileName = "CS_TEST.jpg";
    return imageFileName;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
I changed the code a little :

Also, here is the `imgs` xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/imgs_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShareImage"
        android:text="Share ->"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the filename to previews activity, using your `intent extra`, with your timestamp and `decode` the file to Bitmap, like that:

```
private Bitmap getImage(String  imageFileName) {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root + "/mst_imgs/" + imageFileName);
}
```

Create a `ImageView` into the `layout.xml`. Insert in your `onCreate()`:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setImageBitmap(getImage());
```

Don't forget to add access for read files into the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**---------- Update Code -----------**

I don't know what's happening, I'm passing below my test:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private File imageFolderPath;
private int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getUri());
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

    ImageView imageV = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
    String filename = getImageFileName();
    Bitmap image = getImage(filename);
    imageV.setImageBitmap(image);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Capture is saved to:\n" + imageFolderPath.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You cancelled the capture",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Capture failed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public Uri getUri(){
    imageFolderPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mst_imgs");
    if(!imageFolderPath.exists())
        imageFolderPath.mkdir();

    String imageFullName = imageFolderPath + "/" + getImageFileName();
    File newPic = new File(imageFullName);

    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(newPic);

    return imageUri;
}

private Bitmap getImage(String  imageFileName) {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root + "/mst_imgs/" + imageFileName);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root + "/mst_imgs/CS_TEST.jpg");
}

private String getImageFileName(){
    String imageFileName;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss");
    String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    //imageFileName = "CS_" +timeStamp + ".jpg";
    imageFileName = "CS_TEST.jpg";
    return imageFileName;
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/imgs_webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShareImage"
    android:text="Share ->"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.rodrigo.teste">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks you for your answer. I tried your way but I get `null` result in the `imageView.setImageBitmap(getImage())` line !! even though I get the right `imageFileName` !!

Comment: You are welcome. Only for a test, you can try to change the `"CS_" +timeStamp + ".jpg";` to a fixed name , like `"CS_TEST.jpg";`. To use into the `decodefile(root + "/mst_imgs/CS_TEST.jpg");`.

Comment: Still not working . What I did is: create the `getImage` method exactly as you put it. Then create the `ImageView` in my `xml` layout. Then put the two lines `fdindViewById & setImageBitmap` in the `onCreate()` method`. I already have the permission in the Manifest !! any idea what is wrong ?!

Comment: humm.... not sure. Can you put the Activity code that you want to display the picture, into your question? If is possible include your `layout.xml` too. tks

Comment: Do you believe if I told you that's work for me? =P Let's confirm some values. Is `TAKE_PHOTO_CODE` equal to 1 (int)? Besides the permission of read, in your manifest confirm the permissions `    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.

Comment: And to confirm, do need to automatically displays the picture? 
I got it by pushing the button. If you need to fix it, maybe is better to create a another activity, only to displays the picture.

Comment: ERATA! "_do you need_"*

Comment: Well, 1- the `TAKE_PHOTO_CODE =  0` ... 2- The two permission are already there in the `Manifest` ... 3 - As for the functionality, I need to take the shot using the built-in camera-app, then, after it is saved, displayed it on an activity in my app, then hit a send button to send it to someone .. !!

Comment: I think it is better to mention that I start this activity class from the `MainActivity` class. Check the update

Comment: Please, see my update answer, I'm passing the test of your code.

Comment: Well, it partially works now even though I don't know why. My code is as same as yours. I also said partially because if I cleared the folder where I save my pictures, then took a shot 'x' it will not show on the activity afterward. However, when I take another shot 'y' the activity will show shot 'x' instead. I.e.: it always shows the previously taken picture !!

Comment: This is very wierd... I'm so sorry man! I really don't know how this happening. 'Cause if we creating the file .jpg with the same name, the application will overlaps the file.

Comment: ALL WORKS NOW. Basically my code-practice was rubbish. I had to re-arrange the whole class. Most importantly, I needed to create `setters` and `getters` in order to obtain correct values (I found a lot of null values). I re-arranged everything having your answer in the core of everything. Thank you very much Rodrigo.

Comment: \o/ That's GREAT! No problem, it's was a pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

You now have the file saved to the device, great, what you want to do now is just set it to an image view.

If you're using bitmaps you'll need to use the BitmapFactory and do some other things to take the file and turn it into something that can be set on an imageview, then worry about loading the correct size and so on.

There are plenty of libraries you can use to handle this for you. But I'd say your best option is to just use [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) - you can hand it a File and it will load and display it. I use this and it makes life way easier.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(fileName)).into(imageView);
```

You can also use the file path if it doesn't just load your file straight away.

Hope this helps, and do some more googling! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one problem though, I don't have (or I cannot find) the build.gradle file to add the library !!

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Comment: just a tip- if you're in android studio, you can go to 'Module Settings', then go to the 'Dependencies' tab, then click the green "+", then choose 'Library Dependency'. This will bring you to a screen where you can effectively search for dependencies. Bear in mind that the best way to get these is from the site themselves, but if you know which one you need but don't know the full statement, try this

Comment: I am on Android-Studio. But when I open `Project Structure` (in order to open `Module Settings`, it shows _"Nothign to show"_ . and when I click on the `'+'` sign, I don't see `Library Dependency` !! any suggestions ?!

Comment: click on the "app" folder and you *should* just be able to hit F4, then go across to the dependencies tab- if there's no "app" folder/module, you might have your gradle slightly wrong, no big deal, but you *should* just be able to go in there and see dependencies (make sure the module is selected on the left!). Anyway, did that compile statement allow you to use Picasso? Marvellous piece of kit..

Comment: when you click on _Open Module Setting_  or press _F4_ after cliking on _"app"_ there is no `dependencies tab`... only the `'+'` sign, `'Ok'` and `'Cancel'` buttons .. in the middle there is a meesage saying: _"Nothing to show"_ .

Comment: I'm not sure then- you should have 5 tabs : "Properties", "Signing", "Flavours", "Build types" and "Dependencies"
it's v strange you aren't even seeing anything for properties. Will need to see screenshots honestly. You aren't just sitting in a tab where you have nothing entered, like signing or flavours or build types? What happens when you click the +?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri picUri = data.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = getThumbnail(imageUri);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    InputStream input = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    onlyBoundsOptions.inDither=true;//optional
    onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
    input.close();
    if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1) || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1))
        return null;

    int originalSize = (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight > onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth) ? onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight : onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;

    double ratio = (originalSize > THUMBNAIL_SIZE) ? (originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE) : 1.0;

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
    bitmapOptions.inDither=true;//optional
    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
    input = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
    input.close();
    return bitmap;
}

private static int getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(double ratio){
    int k = Integer.highestOneBit((int)Math.floor(ratio));
    if(k==0) return 1;
    else return k;
}
```

Comment: you should explain the merits of doing this over using a library that will handle it for you